# Getting Partition_Info in athena

Tags: amazon-athena

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.__internal_partitions__
WHERE  table_schema = 's1'
AND table_name = 't1'
ORDER  BY partition_numberenter code here
```

Can we get partition details for all the tables at the same time using the above query ? Like where table_schema IN (s1,s2) AND table_name IN (t1,t2)

Comment: Hi!, I think you are looking for something like `SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.__internal_partitions__;` right?

Comment: Yes but this  command does not work with athena